# Jenkins RBAC plugin for granting access and permissions for jobs inside the folders

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rbac

I am currently using Jenkins RBAC plugin to grant access and permissions to project for the users with the Regex pattern that matches the job.

Now the problem is I have created a folder and given the pattern that matches the folder name and the user was able to access it. But not able to see ant projects inside the folder.

When I give global read permission then the user is able to view the project and also if I give the global configure permission then the user is able to configure the project. This causes the security issue as the permissions are at global level.

I also tried to use the Folder Manage plugin where we can give ownership to the folders. Still its of no use.

Any idea or suggestion in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it, Have to give the permission to any jobs starting in that name.
Say for example I have a folder in the name "Test", but RBAC plugin consider it as a job.
So in that I case I have to give the permission rule like "Test.*" so that any jobs running inside will be accessible with that permission rule.

Hope this helps others who are new in setting up the RBAC plugin in Jenkins